# In 3 way-outcome betting, what is the corresponding 1 back + 1 lay bet of 2 back bet

Tags: gambling

In Soccer-Game we have three outputs, win / draw / loose, with corresponding quotes q1 / q0 / q2. Now suppose we would like to bet x to win and y to draw. We have two back quotes.

In Exchanges, there exists another option, to Lay. Betting of the opposite and taking the role of the bookmaker. Therefore there exists an equivalent lay-quote + back-quote, ie. Lay q2 with x* and back q1 or q0 with y*.

How to get x*, y*?

Comment: I am not sure whether I understood your question correctly, but it seems to be rather similar to this question: [Mathematics of hedging bets](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2029438#2032624).